# Pandas set_index creates NoneType object without inplace=True

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm facing a weird behavior with pandas set_index function. I initilally have this dataframe:

```
      Unnamed: 0          Timestamps   PM10
0            NaN                 NaT   PM10
1            NaN                 NaT  ▒g/m▒
2            NaN 2018-12-31 23:00:00  10.76
3            NaN 2018-12-31 22:00:00   9.46
4            NaN 2018-12-31 21:00:00   8.67
...          ...                 ...    ...
8682         NaN 2018-01-01 04:00:00  25.14
8683         NaN 2018-01-01 03:00:00  31.34
8684         NaN 2018-01-01 02:00:00  36.28
8685         NaN 2018-01-01 01:00:00  21.78
8686         NaN 2018-01-01 00:00:00  20.59
```

I want to drop the first two rows and set the Timestamps as indeces so I do this:

```
df_final = df.drop([0,1]).set_index('Timestamps', drop=True)
```

and I get this dataframe:

```
                     Unnamed: 0   PM10
Timestamps
2018-12-31 23:00:00         NaN  10.76
2018-12-31 22:00:00         NaN   9.46
2018-12-31 21:00:00         NaN   8.67
2018-12-31 20:00:00         NaN  10.42
2018-12-31 19:00:00         NaN  10.04
...                         ...    ...
2018-01-01 04:00:00         NaN  25.14
2018-01-01 03:00:00         NaN  31.34
2018-01-01 02:00:00         NaN  36.28
2018-01-01 01:00:00         NaN  21.78
2018-01-01 00:00:00         NaN  20.59
```

So far so good, but finally I want to re-index the PM10 column by a new time index I have created called t_index, so I do this:

```
data_write = df_final.PM10[-1::-1].reindex(t_index)
```

That is where I get an error:

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

After some debugging I have concluded that set_index is causing this but I can't figure out why, any help is appreciated!

Comment: `print(df_final.PM10[-1::-1])` and `print(t_index)`

Comment: The t_index is the same as the Timestamps. I'm doing this because there are some hourly values missing and they don't have an entry. By re-indexing I can fill those with NaN. The reason why I'm using [-1::-1] is because the timestamps in the dataset are in reversed order (newer to older).

Comment: to sort a Series you can use `sort_index()` (sort by index, you will need it)  or `sort_values()` (sort by values) setting ascending=True or False, 
but if you are going to reindex afterwards, there is no point in ordering, since the order will be the one established later by the index.
On the other hand, if your index is datetime, it is easier to directly use `dataframe.asfreq` or `Series.asfreq` in this case https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.asfreq.html

Comment: Just did this ```df_final.asfreq(freq='1H')``` and it changes nothon to the dataframe, am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I managed to make this work and here is the code that does it:

```
df = df.drop([0,1]).drop("Unnamed: 0", axis=1).set_index('Timestamps', drop=True)
df = df.sort_values(by="Timestamps", ascending=True)

year = 2018
start_index = '{}-01-01 00:00:00'.format(year) # define start of the year
end_index = '{}-12-31 23:00:00'.format(year) # define end of the year
t_index = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=start_index, end=end_index, freq='1h').strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

df_final = pd.to_numeric(df.PM10).resample('H').mean().reindex(t_index)
```

Still not sure what was causing the erro, or why the `.asfreq` method did not work.